# Migrating EAR-Files from Apache Geronimo to tomEE

Tags: java, migration, ear, apache-tomee, geronimo

I'm trying to migrate some EAR-files from Apache Geronimo 3.0.1 to Apache tomEE 7.0.2.

The only reason to migrate is the "death" of Geronimo and it's lack of Java 8 Support and tomEE looks like its successor.

I was able to get the server running in eclipse 4.6.3 and deploy a new dynamic web project but I can't create a EAR-project for tomEE.

Do I have to change the EARs (containing multiple .war-files) into single .war-files? It seems like tomEE has EAR-support (http://tomee.apache.org/deploying-in-tomee.html) but I can't find any info how to create one that will work.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

you can define where is your ear using  in tomee.xml and then just drop your .ear in tomee.base/apps.